# Jboss6EAP java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.registerResolvableDependency

Tags: jboss7.x, nosuchmethoderror

I am moving a simple web application from Jboss 4.3 to Jboss 6 EAP (Jboss AS 7.2). However, I am unable to deploy the war because of the error

```
    07:43:17,773 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Context initialization failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.registerResolvableDependency(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458) [spring-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:356) [spring-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255) [spring-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199) [spring-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45) [spring-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

I am not sure what needs to be done. The Spring libraries the war file uses is version 2.5.5 and is bundled within the war 0 within the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Any help in resolving my problem, would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. Would like to share with others, in case they run into the same issue. The war file we were using had Spring libraries and was included within the war file.

The problem was with the versions of the spring.jar and spring-context.jar. The former was 2.0.3 but the latter was version 2.5.5. I downgraded the spring-context.jar to 2.0.3 and it did the trick.

Not sure, why there was no problem in Jboss 4.3. Anyway, I don't have the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that this problem could persist - after clearing out the dependencies (using exclusions), there could still be a wrong version in the Eclipse classpath.

You can figure this out running f.ex. a test with two methods:

- in Eclipse
- using Maven

  mvn clean test -Dtest=com.example.HelloTest

Compare error messages / the stack traces, they might be different, or the Maven test runs fine while in Eclipse the test fails.